# Possible to Add to Finder Sidebar Since LSSharedFileList is Deprecated?

Tags: swift, macos, sandbox

Looking to add a folder to Finder's sidebar favorites, but it appears all avenues have been fully deprecated when it comes to modern day macOS. Everything `LSSharedFileList`* is now unusable, and even scripting doesn't appear to be an option judging by the output of `sdef /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app`.

Is there any way, preferably sandbox-friendly, to modify sidebar items in Finder from a Swift application?

Comment: Did you find any solution? LSSharedFileListRef still works but i have a bug where the item is not removed from sidebar if called from applicationWillTerminate when the computer shuts down.

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry for being the bearer of "bad news", but there isn't any replacement for `LSSharedFileList`, nor there will be one offered by Apple. The reasoning behind this is they want to prevent developers from using and abusing APIs that may interfere with the user's right to choose how their interface should look like or what rights they want to give to developers to do things behind the users' backs. Some applications abused this freedom and started to add folders to the sidebar without user's consent. The same was true when some powerful companies abused their developer capabilities by adding their apps to the `tcc.db` database to track what their users were doing without express consent. Thus, this is a consequence of bad behaviour, and we developers are paying the price for it.